# Out of Memory Exception When Spawning Multiple Sub-Orchestrators (Work-Item Queue Limit?)

Tags: azure-durable-functions

I'm load testing a `Durable Function` that has a parent orchestrator that creates x number of `sub orchestrators` (currently 5) in parallel (fan out/fan in) that each evenly split whatever amount of records we're testing with across `activity functions` that fan out without limit in parallel (fan out/fan in). Is there a limit to how many items the work-item queue can hold or a rate limit?

When I hit about 30k records (evenly spread across the sub orchestrators whether 5, 3, etc.), I get an `Out Of Memory` exception when spawning the sub-orchestrators whose activity functions would have put the work-item queue at or over the limit of roughly 30k messages.

In one example, with 5 sub-orchestrators creating 10k messages each (50k total), 2 of the sub-orchestrators failed and their 10k records weren't added to the work-item queue and thus only 30k records were run. The exception for both was the following:

```
"message":"Function 'SubOrchestratorName' failed with an unhandled exception.","details":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:
 Exception while executing function: Functions.SubOrchestratorName\r\n --->
 Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException: 
Result: Failure\nException: **System.OutOfMemoryException**: 
 Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.\r\n   at System.Convert.ToBase64String(ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes, Base64FormattingOptions options)\r\n   
 at System.Convert.ToBase64String(Byte[] inArray)\r\n  
 at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Grpc.GrpcOrchestrationRunner.LoadAndRun(String encodedOrchestratorRequest, ITaskOrchestrator implementation, IServiceProvider services)\r\n   
 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext functionContext, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in 
 /_/src/Worker.Extensions.DurableTask/DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.cs:line 32\r\n  
 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) 
 n D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\src\\DotNetWorker.Core\\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 77\r\n   
 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Handlers.InvocationHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationRequest request)
```

I cut the rest as it goes on for quite a bit, but I'm wondering if there's a limit to how many messages the `work-item queue` can hold or if it's rate-limited. That presents a unique challenge, but it seems adding 30k or so seems to be the max for the situation. I will add some retries to see if it's rate-limited, but just wondering if anyone knows of any `work-item queue` limits for Durable Functions as I haven't found anything yet.

Update - Because of [Scale Targets for Queue Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/scalability-targets) I tried adding a retry to space out failed attempts to create a sub-orchestrator using `TaskOptions` as such:

```
var taskOptions = TaskOptions.FromRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy(maxNumberOfAttempts: 10, firstRetryInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), backoffCoefficient: 1.5, maxRetryInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)));
```

and passing it in as the third argument to the call to `CallSubOrchestratorAsync` but that didn't work. I tried using a delay inside of the for loop that creates the sub-orchestrators, also to no avail.